# Is there a way to change my spawn point in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

In Terraria, I built a house a little ways away from where I spawn. But, when I re-join/ respawn, it puts me back at that spawn point, which gets very annoying. Is there a way to move my spawn point?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Build a bed (5 silk, 15 wood), place it and right-click it.

Be sure to place it in valid housing. If correctly done so, you'll see "Spawn point set!".

Comment: Also: the bed should be placed in valid housing.See http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Home#Requirements on what is considered valid housing.

Comment: Is it possible to build a bed on Terraria for Android?